# Grouping tweets and newspaper articles by topic

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, topic-model

i want to implement a software that groups twitter posts to other twitter posts or to newspaper articles with similar topics.

Let's say for example someone tweets about a soccer game and at the same time a newspaper article gets released about the same soccer game. I would like to bundle and group up all tweets and newspaper articles that i can find about that specific football match together.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Would there be an initial query or initial document for which the system searches specifically? Because otherwise you'd have to index all the potential sources of data, like Google does with their huge data centers... Do you have huge data centers? ;)

Comment: The basic idea was to extract some sort of identifying topic of the initial tweet and then querying google news to find matching newspaper articles.

Comment: In this case it's easy: you can just query google directly with the content of the tweet. you could do some preprocessing like removing stop words but it's not really needed since google does it. You could also try to extract the specific topic of interest from the tweet, but again it's likely that google can figure this out better than any custom model.

Comment: Is the use of Google News to enrich the informational content of tweets an effective approach? And how can i group tweets adressing the same topic together?

Comment: Well, this is why I was asking you my first question: it's a quite different problem if the input is one tweet and the goal is just to retrieve some related news articles from google vs. an input of "many tweets" (how many?) that you want to cluster (with respect to documents found with google?). There are potentially answers to these problems, but you need to start by clearly defining which problem you address.